# What happens to variables which are not initialized in DECLARE section in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I am new to oracle PL/SQL

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
a NUMBER(10,2);

begin 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
end ;
```

The above code compiles , but now i want to know what is value stored for variable a , Is it NULL or empty ?

Comment: It will be null. You should be able to prove that with ease. No such thing as an empty number. You can coax the Oracle RDBMS into differentiating null strings from zero length strings but I wouldn't do it if I were you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers are correct but if you wanted to prove it you could do something like the below....

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
a NUMBER(10,2);

begin 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(case when a is null then 'It is null' else 'It is not null' end);
end ;
```

That way you see that it prints It is null, you can then set a to anything else and you will see It is not null.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS208) the initial value is NULL:

> because the default initial value for a scalar variable is NULL